# Partial match 2 columns with conditions from another column

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem Statement**

Want to do `str.contains` between columns of a df with a condition to another column with below condtions

1. 1st want to see either `1_Match` or `1_1_Match` is Yes or No, if it is No then `2_Match` Becomes **Not Applicable**
2. If 1_Match is **Yes** or 1_1_Match is Yes, then want to check if `Country` (EU) is in/contains `Nation`(Europe). If Yes then `2_Match` becomes **Yes**
3. If it doesn't contain or there is no partial match between `Country` (APAC) and `Nation` (India) then `2_Match` becomes **No**

DF1

```
Country          Nation         1_Match   1_1_Match
EU               Europe         Yes       No
MA               MACOPEC        No        No
APAC             INDIA          Yes       No
COPEC            MACOPEC        No        Yes
COPEC            India          No        Yes
```

**Expected Output:**

DF1

```
Country       Nation           1_Match       1_1_Match   2_Match
EU            Europe             Yes           No        Yes
MA            MACOPEC            No            No        Not Applicable
APAC          INDIA              Yes           No        No
COPEC         MACOPEC            No            Yes       Yes
Copec         India              No            Yes       No
```

**Code (Not Working):** I am writing code for condition 2&3 but it is throwing errors and then I want to accommodate condition 1 also

```
df1['2_Match']  = np.where(df1['Country'].str.strip().str.lower().str.contains(df1['Nation'].str.strip().str.lower().astype(str)),'Yes','No')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with list comprehension with `in` for check subtrings between columns:

```
m1 = df['1_Match'] == 'No'
m2 = [c.lower() in n.lower() for c, n in zip(df['Country'], df['Nation'])]
masks = [m1, m2]
vals = ['Not Applicable','Yes']

df['2_Match'] = np.select(masks, vals, default='No')
print (df)
  Country   Nation 1_Match         2_Match
0      EU   Europe     Yes             Yes
1      MA  MACOPEC      No  Not Applicable
2    APAC    INDIA     Yes              No
```

EDIT:

```
m1 = df['1_Match'] == 'No'
m2 = [c.lower() in n.lower() for c, n in zip(df['Country'], df['Nation'])]

m3 = df['1_1_Match'] == 'Yes'

masks = [m3, m1, m2]
vals = ['Yes', 'Not Applicable','Yes']

df['2_Match'] = np.select(masks, vals, default='No')
print (df)
  Country   Nation 1_Match 1_1_Match         2_Match
0      EU   Europe     Yes        No             Yes
1      MA  MACOPEC      No        No  Not Applicable
2    APAC    INDIA     Yes        No              No
3   COPEC  MACOPEC      No       Yes             Yes
```

EDIT 2:

```
masks = [m1 & ~m3, m2]
vals = ['Not Applicable','Yes']
print (df)
  Country   Nation 1_Match 1_1_Match         2_Match
0      EU   Europe     Yes        No             Yes
1      MA  MACOPEC      No        No  Not Applicable
2    APAC    INDIA     Yes        No              No
3   COPEC  MACOPEC      No       Yes             Yes
4   COPEC  India        No       Yes             No
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!! One more query, if I have one more column say `1_1_Match` and want to apply same conditions 2&3 basis either of `1_Match` or `1_1_Match` is **Yes**. Can we tweak solution little bit or it would be altogether a new question!!

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - I am a bit confused, so need get output only by `True`s in both? And if No in both get `Not Applicable` ?

Comment: NO!!! The 1st is to check 1_Match..id `Yes` then everything happens according to the solution you provided. If 1_Match is No but 1_1_Match is `Yes` then also same logic as applied above should hold.

Comment: Check Line 4 of the sample `df`, it is taking the example I explained!!

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - yes, give me some time.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - Can you check `m3 = df['1_1_Match'] == 'Yes'

masks = [m3, m1, m2]
vals = ['Yes', 'Not Applicable','Yes']` ?

Comment: Yes, it is working!! If you can append this onto your answer, it will help others also!!

Comment: In your answer above, I see wherever `1_1_Match` is `Yes` then `2_Match` is `Yes`. Whereas I want to check if `1_1_Match` is `Yes` then check for `Country` is in `Nation` and then appropriately put `Yes/No`. Edited the question also

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - Is possible create new?

Comment: Stackoverflow won't take it as it would be duplicate of this one!!

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - ok, so please add inpu/output data.

Comment: Added, please check row 5

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - Can you check `masks = [m1 & ~m3, m2 | m3]` and 
`vals = ['Not Applicable','Yes']` ?

Comment: Still showing the same result!! For any `1_1_Match` it is still coming `Yes` irrespective of country with nation match. In line 5 of the sample `df` 1_1_Match is Yes but COPEC doesn't contain/match India and hence 2_Match becomes `No`

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - oops, you are right, need `masks = [m1 & ~m3, m2]`